# How to typeset this field extension diagram using xymatrix

Tags: xy-pic

I'd like to typeset the following diagram:

[image]

I tried the following code:

```
$$
\xymatrix{
B\ar@{-}[d] &
\save[]+<0em,1em>*+{C}\ar@{-}[l]\restore &
\save[]+<0em,2em>*+{D}\ar@{-}[l]\restore \\
A
}
$$
```

But it produces

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks.

[EDIT] Thanks to @Phil Hirschhorn, finally I use this slighly modified version:

```
$$
\xymatrix{
B\ar@{-}[d] &
\save[]+<0em,1em>*+{C}="c"\ar@{-}[l]\restore &
\save[]+<0em,2em>*+{D}\ar@{-}"c"\restore \\
A
}
$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two versions:

```
\begin{displaymath}
  \xymatrix@C=3em{
    && {D}\\
    & {C} \ar@{-}[ur]\\
    {B}  \ar@{-}[ur]\\
    {A} \ar@{-}[u]
  }
\end{displaymath}

\begin{displaymath}
  \xymatrix{
    {B} \ar@{-}[d]
    \ar@{} []+<4em,6ex>*+{C}="c"
    \ar@{-} "c"
    \ar@{} []+<8em,12ex>*+{D}="d"
    \ar@{-} "c";"d" \\
    A
  }
```

\end{displaymath}

[image: Diagrams]

In the first, we just used a larger grid, leaving the first column of the first two rows empty.

In the second, we placed the `C` and `D` without drawing any arrows, but we named those objects so that we could then draw arrows (without arrowheads) to and/or from those objects.  Thus, if you change the dimensions that were used to place the objects, the arrows will adjust automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look on `tikz-cd` which would look like this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash}]
                &             & D \\[-5ex]
                & C\arrow{ur} &   \\[-5ex]
    B\arrow{ur} &             &   \\
    A\arrow{u}  &             &
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

NB: If you are using LaTeX, please don't use `$$...$$` as it is deprecated.